# Adding more input fields after button using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

So i have displayed two input fields the user can enter information in them. I also have another button "add" that allows the user to add another set of two input fields to enter data.

This is my current view of the what i have but i need to add the functionality of adding input fields into my viewModel so it is available upon user click.

[jsFiddle of html](https://jsfiddle.net/roqp6761/)

I would like to add the functionality of clicking the add button to be placed in like:

```
self.addName = function(){//return new input fields to user}
```

and in my html i would have `<a href="#" onclick="addName()">`

Comment: You didn't share any of your viewModel code... What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, you need to have observables in array to bind to multiple inputs. 
You do it like this:

```
<div class="addNames">
    <!-- ko foreach: ViewModel.values -->
    <div class="fname" >
        <input data-bind="value: $data.value" placeholder="Add your fname..." contenteditable/>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div class="addBtn">
    <a data-bind="click: ViewModel.addValue"> Add Name</a>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
 ViewModel = {
        values: ko.observableArray([
            {value: ko.observable('initial value')}
        ]),
        addValue: function(){
            ViewModel.values.push({ value: ko.observable('')});
            ViewModel.values().forEach(function(data){
                console.log(data.value());
            });
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x5wu7gsy/